# If $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=l$ then $\lim_{x\to \infty}e^{-x}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n!}x^n=l$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(a_n)_{n\ge1}$ be a convergent sequence  of complex numbers $$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=l$$

How to prove that $$\lim_{x\to +\infty}e^{-x}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n!}x^n=l\;,\;x\in\mathbb{R}$$

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: I vaguely remember that this question had already been answered somewhere on MSE

Comment: Anyway the most basic epsilon-delta (or, in this case, epsilon-x) approach wins (and this is **not** complex analysis...).

Comment: This is a summability method called Borel summability. In fact it is  a weighted mean with the cofficcients $(\frac{x^n}{n!})$. Like the arithmetical man, weighted means are also regular so they conserve limit points. You may also look for Abel summability method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is easier to write with the sums starting at 0 and does not change the result.

$$e^{-x}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n!}x^n - l 
=e^{-x}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_n - l}{n!}x^n
$$

Now cut the sum in two parts: for $N$ big enough, 
$$
n>N\implies |a_n - l|<\varepsilon
\\
\left|e^{-x}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n!}x^n - l \right|
\le e^{-x}\sum_{n=0}^{N}\frac{|a_n - l|}{n!}x^n + \varepsilon
e^{-x}\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}
$$

the first part goes to 0 because $\exp$ dominates the polynomial;
and using the fact that $x>0\implies e^{-x}\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!} \le 1$:

$$\limsup \left|e^{-x}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n!}x^n - l \right|
\le \varepsilon$$